# ¿Cómo hago para indexar una tabla por columna Date?

Tags: python, lista, websocket, binance

tengo esta tabla:

```
if msg['e'] != 'error':
                #print(msg)
                btc_price['Close'] = msg['c']
                btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
                btc_price['ask'] = msg['a']
                btc_price['error'] = False
                btc_price['Open']=msg['o']
                btc_price['High']=msg['h']
                btc_price['Low']=msg['l']
                btc_price['Volume']=msg['v']
                btc_price['Date']=msg['E']
                
                
                #print(btc_price)
                return df.append(btc_price)
```

que suelta la lista así:

```
{'error': False, 'Close': '0.00317700', 'bid': '0.00317500', 'ask': '0.00317700', 'Open': '0.00340400', 'High': '0.00343500', 'Low': '0.00311300', 'Volume': '6875559701.00000000', 'Date': 1644525989517}
```

pero necesito indexarla por date. He intentado indexarlo con esto en el return:

```
return df.append(btc_price) and df.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
```

pero me da el siguiente error (al querer usar esa lista):

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

¿como puedo solucionar este enredo de lista?

Comment: por lo que veo ... creo que lo que obtengo son datos de una diccionario ... ¿como puedo hacer para pasarlos a datos como un float?

Comment: con float(msg['o']) paso de str a float ... pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error ... ya no se que es?¿